# iterator.cycle function called twice return the same iterator (with same memory adress)

Tags: python, memory-address, cycle

On python 3.7, I expect to get a new memory address (and cycle) each time I call iterator.cycle, however, this piece of code duplicates 2 iterators on 4:

```
from itertools import cycle

cycles = [[None] * 2] * 2
s = set()
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        c =  cycle("ab")
        cycles[i][j] =c
        s.add(hex(id(c)))
        print(hex(id(c)))

print(len(s))
```

It prints:

```
0x7efe576cc370
0x7efe576cc3c0
0x7efe576cc410
0x7efe576cc370
3
```

So object `0x7efe576cc370` is used twice. On the other hand, this code works:

```
from itertools import cycle

cycles = []

for _ in range(1000):
    c = cycle("ab")
    cycles.append(c)

s = set([hex(id(c)) for c in cycles])
print(len(s)) # 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the way that you are constructing the `cycles` object.

When you use the `*` operator on a list, the new list that is returned contains multiple references to the original list, not copies of the original list.

As a result, `cycles` is a two item list, where both elements point to the same list, and thus changes made to `cycles[1][0]` also apply to  `cycles[0][0]`

When you assign to `cycles[1][0]`, you also overwrite the item at `cycles[0][0]`, which deletes the previous item.

As to why this means `s` has a length of 3, this is due to the way the object allocator / garbage collector interact.

For anything but the innermost list, you should use a list comprehension to construct the object.

```
 cycles = [[None] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
```

This will produce a list that is suitably constructed, and you code will work fine

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, this is the first time I used * for nested lists. I didn't know the * operator duplicate reference to the object instead of duplicating the object itself, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A new object is created at each iteration however docs for [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function says the following:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
>   guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
>   lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the
>   same id() value.**
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
>   memory.

You proved this statement in your second example where you keep all objects so their lifetimes overlap.

**Example 1 (x2 unique IDs):**

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> for i in range(5):
...     c = cycle('ab')
...     print(hex(id(c)))
... 
0x7fdac5d54140
0x7fdac5d54180
0x7fdac5d54140
0x7fdac5d54180
0x7fdac5d54140
```

**Example 2 (x5 unique IDs):**

```
>>> store = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     c = cycle('ab')
...     store.append(c)
...     print(hex(id(c)))
... 
0x7fdac5e20680
0x7fdac5d17340
0x7fdac5d17300
0x7fdac5d172c0
0x7fdac5d17240
```